# Can't find a header given by proxy Python Requests Scrapoxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Scrapoxy adds it's own header when using it's proxies, it's 
"x-cache-proxyname". Now whenever I make a request through Requests it can't find the said header. Sometimes this code finds it:

```
name = req.history[0].headers['x-cache-proxyname']
```

But this just doesn't work every time, often it gives me an error saying 'list-index is out of range' , which happens when req.history is empty. Can someone explain why and tell me how to fix this?

Comment: And no, it's not showing up in req.headers.